# Broadcast через весь Интернет

Tags: udp

Подскажите, возможен ли broadcast через весь Интернет?
Если да - то прошу объяснить как именно (нужно ли давать разрешения роутеру или таблицу маршрутизации компьютера менять (iptables в случае с Linux)) и т.п.
Если нет - то тоже почему.
На первый взгляд кажется, что точно нельзя, но хотелось бы узнать мнение более подкованных в этом вопросе людей, чем я.

Answer (score 1):

Броадкаст на адрес `255.255.255.255` и подобные невозможен - он не пересечет границу роутера.

Мультикаст невозможен, так как для него нужно, чтобы у всех провайдеров в мире был настроен и разрешен одинаковый адрес мультикаста.

Так что увы, нет.

Аналогичный вопрос [на enSO](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/28518/33157)